# rc522 nothing received in SL3 Mifare card

Tags: aes, rfid, mifare

Why the card in SL3 returns nothing on the reader mfrc522?

I send the command with this format ( iso 14443-4 (after sending rats)) 
PCB + CID + INF + CRC => (INF contain command from datasheet mifare Plus) 
If I trying  authenticate  in **valid block**, then nothing recive. I'm recive **valid** information of error when block or length is invalid. But nothing recive if the command are valid. Please, help!

First **send invalid** command, second **send valid** command:

```
      PCB   CID    4-byte command          CRC
```

Send:   0x0A, 0x02, 0x70, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, crc1 ,crc2;

Recive:  0x0A, 0x02, 0x09, 0x1F, 0x78;

Error code  0x09 => Block Number is not valid

Send : 0x0A, 0x02, 0x70, 0x00, 0x40, 0x00, crc1 ,crc2;

Recive: nothing

Comment: You need to include code, and output to make your question answerable.

Comment: Have you tried with another transceiver on another board ? I had similar issues with a poorly decoupled transceiver board. Transceiver was crashing in the middle of the transaction. It worked with MFP because transactions are shorter.

Comment: Yes, whith  acr1252u this work perfectly, but.. rc522 fail..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mfrc522 doesn't support the iso standard: 14443-4.

The: PN532 does I believe.